# Shortcut - CTRL+ALT+DEL Change Password

Tags: c#, windows-authentication

I am looking to be able to direct a user to the Windows CTRL+ALT+DEL Change Password screen as built into Windows but I have not been able to find any lead into making this happen.
This is something that I want to use instead of going via a less secure method of creating my own Windows form for this.
Is there a command line shortcut, C# or PowerShell string that can load this screen for a user when required?

Notes about this,

I have tried to contact saslib@ms but email have bounced.

The 'net user' command does not help as I need this for domain (AD-DS) user logons.

Many thanks all

[Windows 10 Change Password Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0swpn.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This can be achieved through the SendSAS function in **Sas.dll** included in the [Microsoft Windows Software Development Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279). This function needs to be invoked in C#.

You could also build a custom form which updates the users password directly in the AD.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain ))
{
  using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName ))
  {
      user.SetPassword( "newpassword" );
      // or
      user.ChangePassword( "oldPassword", "newpassword" );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, not possible is a very bold statement.
I have several forms that will do this and almost every time the question is asked, "Is this secure?" and you can prove it secure 100 ways to the moon yet people still argue it.
Using built in Windows Functionality has always been possible, just sometime very difficult. I have always found an answer even if this takes months.
There will be a way to do this, but I am still testing and googling.
Thanks,

Comment: Note that you only need the SDK on Vista, `sas.dll` is included in all later versions of Windows.  Also by default SendSAS() can only be called by Ease of Access applications running on the secure desktop.  You can use group policy to change the rules.

Comment: Once you've got the SAS working, you'd still have to select the "Change Password" option.  It should be possible to send a keystroke or a window message to LogonUI.exe to do this (unsupported of course!) but your code will have to be running on the secure desktop.  (Presumably there's a supported way to do that, but I'm not familiar with it.)

Comment: Thanks guys, this information has got me thinking further and I am investigating again. Looking at the Win 8.1 SDK as older versions will not install in Windows 10. Looking into shgina.dll as well. I will update soon